# Can someone please explain np.less_equal.outer(range(1,18),range(1,13))

Tags: python, numpy

I was debugging a code written by someone who has left the organization and came across a line, which uses `np.less_equal.outer` & `np.greater_equal.outer` functions. I know that `np.outer` creates a Cartesian cross product of two 1-dimensional arrays and creates two arrays, and `np.less_equal` compares the element of two arrays and returns true or false. Can someone please explain how this combined form works.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`less_equal` and `greater_equal` are special types of `numpy` functions called `ufunc`s, in that they have extendible functionalities, including `accumulate`, `at`, and `outer`.

In this case [`ufunc.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) extends the function to work similarly to the outer product - but while the actual outer product would be `multiply.outer`, this instead does the greater or less than comparison.

So you get a 2d array of booleans corresponding to each element of the first array, and whether they are greater or less than each of the elements in the second array.

```
np.less_equal.outer(range(1,18),range(1,13))
Out[]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True, ...,  True,  True,  True],
       ..., 
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

EDIT: a much more pythonic way of doing this would be:

```
np.triu(np.ones((18, 13), dtype = bool), 0)
```

That is, the upper triangle of a boolean array of shape `(18, 13)`

Comment: I think it should be `np.triu(np.ones((18-1, 13-1), dtype = bool), 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html#numpy.ufunc.outer), we have that for one-dimensional arrays `A` and `B`, the operation `np.less_equal.outer(A, B)` is equivalent to:

```
m = len(A)
n = len(B)
r = empty(m, n)

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        r[i,j] = (A[i] <= B[j])
```

Here's the mathematical representation of the result:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

here is an example:

```
np.less_equal([4, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2])
array([False,  True,  True])
np.greater_equal([4, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2])
array([ True, True, False], dtype=bool)
```

and first the outer function

```
np.outer(range(1,2), range(1,3))
array([[1 2 3],
       [2 4 6],
       )
```

hope that helps.